# haxe case pattern reuseing - maybe as a variable

Tags: pattern-matching, haxe

Is there any way to save patterns in haxe? I have several switch functions, and some of them have the same pattern, and to make the code cleaner, I'd like to save them to a common array or something.
So I have something like

```
switch (field) {
     case 'x' | 'y' | 'color' : doThis();
} 
//...other function...
switch (field) {
     case 'x' | 'y' | 'color' : doThat();
}
```

and I want to have something like

```
myPattern = 'x' | 'y' | 'color';

switch (field) {
     case myPattern : doThis();
} 
//...other function...
switch (field) {
     case myPattern : doThat();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use an [extractor](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-extractors.html).

```
class Test {
    static function myPattern(str:String):Bool {
        return switch (str) {
            case 'x' | 'y' | 'color':
                true;
            case _:
                false;
        }
    }
    static function main():Void {
        var field = "x";
        switch (field) {
            case myPattern(_) => true:
                trace('myPattern');
            case _:
                trace('$field is not myPattern');
        }
    }
}
```

Just one down side: when using an extractor, exhaustiveness check could not discover the pattern being matched in the extractor:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    A;
    B;
    C;
}

class Test {
    static function ab(str:MyEnum):Bool {
        return switch (str) {
            case A | B:
                true;
            case _:
                false;
        }
    }
    static function main():Void {
        var field = A;
        switch (field) {
            case ab(_) => true:
                trace('A|B');
            case C:
                trace('$field is not A|B');
        }
    }
}
```

will result in error:

```
Test.hx:19: characters 10-15 : Unmatched patterns: B | A
Test.hx:19: characters 10-15 : Note: Patterns with extractors may require a default pattern
```

If that happen, just add a `case _:` at the end and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store the patterns the way you want. The compiler do some of the work at compile-time and cannot optimize patterns that are only available at runtime. What you can do is reversing the pattern:

```
function evaluate(test : String , patternA : Void-> Void, patternB : Void -> Void) {
  switch test {
    case 'x' | 'y' | 'color' : patternA();
    case _ : patternB(); 
  }
}
```

Of course I don't know what you are trying to achieve so it is difficult to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also(and I believe it is the cleanest way) use one switch to convert your value to some enum exactly representing the cases you need and use a simple and more readable switch later.